# How to bypass undefined offset 1 in laravel

Tags: laravel

please help to bypass this array....

This function suppose to return 2 user, but initially when they first register is only 1 user available which is the one that will work for "$right" but when it get to "$left" it return "undefined offset 1"

```
$direct = $this->loaduser($userid);

$right = $this->loaduserdirect($direct[0]->user_id);

$left = $this->loaduserdirect(isset($direct[1]->user_id));

if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($direct[0]->boosted == 1) || ($direct[1]- 
>boosted == 1)){
if (isset($bonus['point']))
    $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

if (isset($bonus['totalultimarefbonus']))
    $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus- 
>cash+$bonus['totalultimarefbonus'];

} else if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($direct[0]->boosted == 1) && 
($direct[1]->boosted == 0)){
if (isset($bonus['point']))
    $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

if (isset($bonus['ultimarefbonus']))
    $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus->cash+$bonus['ultimarefbonus'];

} else if(($user->boosted == 1) && ($direct[0]->boosted == 0) && 
($direct[1]->boosted == 1)){
if (isset($bonus['point']))
    $stageBonus->point = $stageBonus->point+$bonus['point'];

if (isset($bonus['ultimarefbonus']))
    $stageBonus->cash = $stageBonus->cash+$bonus['ultimarefbonus'];
```

Comment: that means the `$direct` doesn't have value at index 1, and please provide little more information about what you are trying to do, and the code of the file you are working on

Comment: Yes direct don't have index 1

Answer (score 0):

I Would make this:

```
$direct = $this->loaduser($userid);

$right = $this->loaduserdirect($direct[0]->user_id);

if(count($direct) > 1) {
  $left = $this->loaduserdirect($direct[1]->user_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks the answer you provide works but when it leaves that particular stage to where it will checks it still give error undefined offset 1